# Backbutton disappear on second call Swift

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I suddenly got problem with my NavigationController.
When I click first time on the cell in paren VC it shows my destination View. Here I can switch back without any problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7eHs.png)

When I click the same or other cell again I switch again to the destination but coming back there are no back chevron in my parent View.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPhw3.png)

what can I do?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was just a function in ViewDidLoad I implement for disabling the title for back button.